# Basic Questions On Managing Users And Permissions in Sharepoint with C#

Tags: c#, development-environment, sharepoint-online, user-permissions

I want to develop an application that will manage users and permissions on Sharepoint.  I don't want to add apps or parts to Sharepoint, just manage users and permissions.  Here are my questions:

1. If I just want to manage users and permissions, can I create a
   development environment on Windows 10 Desktop or Windows Server
   running Sharepoint?
2. Do you know of an online tutorial with code
       samples in C# that shows how to manage users and permissions on
       Sharepoint?

Thank you for any assistance you can give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using SharePoint online,you could use SharePoint CSOM api for such requirement.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/manage-sharepoint-users-and-groups

This can be done in several different solutions(PowerShell/client side app/Azure app etc.).
Suppose you develop a cosole/winform application, you just need Visual Studio and install CSOM in your server.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM

Comment: Lee, thanks for the answer and the links.  Can I clarify one point.  Can my Winform development environment be on Windows 10?